# Rendering & in xslt

Tags: php, xslt

hello i am having trouble with my analytic script 
Actually i want to print & in xslt without breaking it, so that it should be render as `&` not as `&amp;` in view source. here is my code :

```
src="//flex.msn.com/mstag/tag/xxxx-xxxx-4123-b7ee-xxxxx/analytics.html?dedup=1&amp;domainId=xxxx&amp;type=1&amp;revenue={$promochktotal}
```

i have also used

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='no'>&amp;</xsl:text>
```

but it result in showing `&amp;` in view source but i want `&`

Comment: Why do you want `&` in the source? `&amp;` should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to represent an ampersand in XML is as the entity reference `&amp;`. Why are you trying to do it an incorrect way?

Comment: Actually my analytic script is not executing and showing error because of &amp; thats why i wan to know can we make & to appear as it as in view source

Comment: If your "analytic script" isn't accepting `&amp;` then presumably it's not processing the data using an XML parser. If you want to use a format that isn't XML, then it's best to avoid XML-based tools like XSLT.